# Guidance on a proof regarding the uniqueness/existence of the nth root of x.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, real-numbers, epsilon-delta

So in a previous proof I had to show that given $y\in\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon >0$, show that for some $\delta>0$, if $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|u-y|<\delta$ then $|u^n-y^n|<\epsilon$. After some trouble I was able to prove this but now once again I am having trouble with this statement.

The current proof I'm working on that given $x > 0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that there is a unique $y > 0$ such that $y^n = x.$ The problem says I am supposed to do this using the previously mentioned proof, however other than the fact that both have a power of $n$ in statement I can't see the relation.

I know that I should probably use l.u.b. and the fact that the previous proof showed that $f(y)=y^n$ is continuous but I'm not sure where to start putting the pieces together.

Comment: Surprisingly similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819329/how-to-prove-that-yn-x-has-a-unique-solution-namely-y-x1-n .

Comment: @EricTowers I'm not asking for a proof, just some guidance on how to begin. I've only just started my real analysis course, and these types are proof a tad foreign to me.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, wouldn't it be much simpler to show that $y\mapsto y^n$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$?